# How to select different data based on column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Currently I have

- `Payroll` table with columns `Payroll_ID`, `Payroll_Name`
- `Paycode` table with columns `Paycode_ID`, `PayCode_Desc`, `Payroll_ID`

The Payroll_ID column can be null in "Paycode" table, when it's null, it means All Payrolls, if it's not, then it means a specific payroll in "Payroll" table.

I would like to do things like following (This is pseudo code, just to express my intention):

```
SELECT 
    PC.Paycode_ID,  
    PC.PayCode_Desc + ' - All Payrolls" AS PayCode_Desc 
FROM 
    Paycode PC 
WHERE
    PC.Payroll_ID = null;

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    PC.Paycode_ID,  
    PC.PayCode_Desc + PR.Payroll_Name AS PayCode_Desc 
FROM
    Paycode PC, Payroll PR 
WHERE
    PC.Payroll_ID != null AND PC.Payroll_ID == PR.Payroll_ID;
```

How I can achieve this in one statement(important)? Thank you so much in advance! Also please feel free to edit the topic as I'm not sure I phrase it right :)

Comment: It's `WHERE`, not `WHEN`.... also: you cannot compare `NULL` with the usual equal or not equal operators - you can **only** use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: For your second query: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Hi @marc_s  I meant to have one statement to achieve, not two separates :)

Comment: As I mentioned I'm just using pseudo code to express my intention, I don't know how to achieve and that's why come with this question :)

Comment: For future reference: SQL uses `=` for equality not `==`, but I guess it's just a typo in the last query as you got it right earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this into a single statement:

```
SELECT 
    PC.Paycode_ID,  
    PC.PayCode_Desc + ISNULL(PR.Payroll_Name, ' - all payrolls') AS PayCode_Desc 
FROM
    Paycode PC
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Payroll PR ON PC.Payroll_ID = PR.Payroll_ID
```

If there's no corresponding row in the `Payroll` table, then `PR.Payroll_Name` will be `NULL` and will be replaced with `- all payrolls` instead.

Also: use **proper** ANSI/ISO `JOIN` syntax to make your life easier!

Comment: Thank you, that what I'm looking for : ) You are very knowledgeable, I'll bear in mind about the syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PC.Paycode_ID
, PC.PayCode_Desc + ISNULL(PR.Payroll_Name, ' - All payrolls') AS PayCode_Desc
FROM Paycode PC
  LEFT JOIN Payroll PR ON PC.Payroll_ID = PR.Payroll_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with the first one (except the random double quote)

For the second I would suggest join syntax -- this is quite common and makes things clearer.

Then you can "combine them" with a union all

```
SELECT 
    PC.Paycode_ID,  
    PC.PayCode_Desc + ' - All Payrolls' AS PayCode_Desc 
FROM Paycode PC 
WHERE PC.Payroll_ID = null;
  UNION ALL
SELECT 
    PC.Paycode_ID,  
    PC.PayCode_Desc + PR.Payroll_Name AS PayCode_Desc 
FROM Paycode P
JOIN Payroll PR ON PC.Payroll_ID = PR.Payroll_ID;
```